# Random SQL Server Timeouts during a small window of time at random times

Tags: sql-server, performance, timeout, disk

I have a weird situation at certain times I get these errors sent to me via email.  This last one lasted 10 minutes. My heavy queries start to timeout.  The event, database and IIS logs look just fine so I am baffled.  Could this be a disk issue, and if so how can I find out?

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out

Generated: Wed, 16 Apr 2014 23:05:20 GMT

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
```

Comment: This is more one for Server Fault, isn't it? Do you have any logs or any idea of what scheduled jobs might be running at that time?

Comment: could be lots of reasons.....are backups (or other jobs)  running at that time?

Comment: My host said not backsup externally, I dont either.  I backup the transaction log file every hour but thats been fine for three days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PerfMon to [analyze disk bottleneck](http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/performance/monitor-counters-to-analyze-disk-bottleneck).
Then [memory pressure](http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/performance/monitor-counters-to-analyze-memory-pressure).
And then [issues on the network](http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/performance/monitor-counters-to-analyze-network-bottleneck).

Comment: What was the problem behind?